# Android: how can a user download an image from my app

Tags: android, download

So basically I'm creating an app that displays many pictures and I want to allow the user to download these photos. What would be the best way to make this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "allow the user to download these photos"? Please explain the exact user experience that you are looking to provide.

Comment: When the user presses a button, the picture willl be saved on his phone and he could find it in his photo gallery. I'm sort of new to programming so hopefully this would help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm creating an app that displays many pictures

Either the pictures are on the user's device, or they are not.

> When the user presses a button, the picture willl be saved on his phone and he could find it in his photo gallery

If the pictures are already on the user's device, most likely they are already in [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and can be viewed in gallery-type apps.

If, instead, you are downloading the images to show them in your app, you can copy the downloaded images to external storage yourself, or perhaps download them straight to external storage in the first place. Then, use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to teach `MediaStore` about them, as most gallery apps ask the `MediaStore` for a list of the indexed images.

Comment: Okkay thank you very much.